# System.console().readLine() requires newLine sign before it actually reads something

Tags: java

I have a problem with reading user input using the Console class.

The `readLine` method reads every typed input until new line is typed, and after that it actually reads the input it returns later (after typing new line for the second time).

I wonder if this has something to do with input buffering.
I tried to write a new line sign into the Console object:

```
cons.writer ().println (System.getProperty ("line.separator"));
```

before attempting to read, but it didn't help.

I use the Console class because of its `readPassword` method (which I have the same problem with).

```
Console cons = System.console();
username = String(cons.readLine(format, message));
password = String(cons.readPassword(format, message));
```

I also must add that this code runs in a loop until username and password are ok.

In every iteration except the first one, this code works fine.

Comment: try flushing the writer after writing the new line

Comment: New line is writen to command line regardless of whether writer was flushed or not. Unfortuanelly it doesn't work.

Comment: So can you please put the "reading" code, or alternatively- use Scanner class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. `readLine()` reads a line, and lines are terminated by a newline, and `readLine()` blocks until it gets a newline, or EOS. If you don't want that behaviour, don't call `readLine()`.

Comment: But it does not work the way you described for me. I need to type a new line before it reads any input and it returns after typing second new line...

Comment: @user1511469 It returns the username after you type one newline, and the password after you type another. But as your code doesn't actually compile it is impossible to comment further. I don't know why you're trying to turn a String into a  String.

Comment: It'd hard to show all the code so it compiles. The issue I described occurs even if I prompt for username only. This prompt takes place after many complex operations made by my command line application. In the begining of the whole process it works fine. But not later. I bielieve it has something to do with keyboard buffer or something. I cannot find any usefull information about it.

Comment: @user1511469 If you reduce your code to what you have posted here and make it compile you will find it executes as described above. Ergo the problem is elsewhere. Possibly you are reading the console via some other means elsewhere?

Comment: I know that this code should be ok. I just wanted to know if maybe my problem is typical somehow and it has a solution someone here will know;)

Comment: @user1511469 The problem is typical of many posts to SO in that you have posted the working code instead of the code where the problem is. Clearly you have another read of the console somewhere, possibly using a `BufferedInputStream`, or even one that interleaves between these two calls. You're going to have to find it.